# JFileChooser with no textArea

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jfilechooser

I'm maybe just missing something very simple but I'm unable to display a text area on the `JFileChooser` that I created and I unable to find the solution to this problem over the Internet. I would precise that I'm working on OSX and already tried `setDialogType`.

I'm still stucked with this UI:

[image]

I really need the textarea (to set filename) and it'll be better if I could keep the OSX-like UI.

To be more precise, I'd to add the red textarea of this picture:

[image]

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. Then people that use the same OS can test the code to see if they have the same problem.

Comment: Actually already referenced bug, https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=219555 (a friend of mine already experienced it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved the bug by changing the UI style and I've to concede that I'm not very happy with this kind of resolution but it's two lines of code and should not introduce any bug; just break a bit the workflow I designed. It's still the best for minimal changes; if you don't wanna to do this, I guess that you could build you own dialog but requires much more time.

I let the "magical" code there:

```
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // If you got no chance ;)
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I made a mistake and used the wrong method. I used `showOpenDialog(Component parent)` instead of `showDialog(Component parent, String approveButtonTitle)`. At the end you can have what you want by writting something like this:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
String title = isLoad ? "Load the game" : "Save the game";
int type = isLoad ? JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG:JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG;
fc.setDialogType(type);
fc.showDialog(null, title);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the type to `SAVE_DIALOG`. This will give you the text field that you want (the difference between `OPEN_DIALOG` and `SAVE_DIALOG` is entirely cosmetic). You will want to manually override the text of the title bar and save button to read "open" in order to make it clear to the user what the dialog box is for. You will also need to implement something to do in case the user enters a file name that does not exist.

Comment: Yeah, as I mentioned I tried to set the Constant. And that's also why I posted because it's making no difference... (absolutely none). I even made a `getDialogType` and I get what I set (how surprising...). And yes title and all this kind of stuff will be improved but that's not the priority, I want my textarea! ;)